# Error : interpolate() was renamed to interpolateNode() in Reanimated 2. Please use interpolateNode() instead

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I have a Small problem getting this to work without warnings or Errors

I stumbled into this Error trying to get this to work, following a step by step tutorial on here from this tutorial https://medium.com/@ritikjain1272/making-drawer-navigator-and-a-splash-screen-on-your-react-native-app-2fb561ee17f1

Now I have installed everything correctly, then it gives me this warning  `interpolate() was renamed to interpolateNode() in Reanimated 2. Please use interpolateNode() instead`

How Can I resolve this , Downgrading gives a further Error.

This is what the `Package.json` Looks like

```
{
  "name": "**********",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.7.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.13.15",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.13.10",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**Edit**

The image after downgrading I get

[image: Capture.png]

Comment: You need to include it in your babel config

Answer (score 0):

You have installed the latest stable [`react-native-reanimated`](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/releases/tag/2.1.0) version, whilst in the tutorial the version [`1.7.0`](https://github.com/Rits1272/DrawerNavigation/blob/master/app/package.json#L17) is being used.

So you'll have to change your `react-native-reanimated` version to `1.7.0`. Change the version in your `package.json` file:

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
  ...
}
```

And then run `npm install` and `npx pod-install`/`cd ios && pod install` if you're running it on iOS.

Comment: I did as u said , Please see the Error above

Comment: Remove `node_modules` folder and then run `npm install` again

Comment: Done, still the same with the Error above